# CNN Color Invariance

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

To detect a specific object that can have any color, if we train our model with images containing that object with just a few colors (e.g. 2 or 3 colors), will the performance of our model's predictions be worse for images containing that object with different colors than the ones used on training?

If so, what is the best way to attain color invariance? (Examples and references to credible sources would be much appreciated.)